# Cast from type ‘DBNULL’ to type ‘Date’ is not valid (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

```
Error :
Cast from type ‘DBNULL’ to type ‘Date’ is not valid
```

This error occurs in the company's application  recently and I don't have the source code of it .

But I've its DB (`SQL 2000`)

How could I solve it from the Database?

The actual design of the column that I thought it caused that issue is ( small date time --and allow null values) when I tried to uncheck the null option . The server asks me to break a foreign key relationship..And I do't know how could I do it safely?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the application language: `C#` or `Java`?

Comment: Really I don't exactly know ..But I don't have the source code of it I only have the db

Comment: Then why did you add these tags? How could they help?

Comment: You've got nulls in a date column, and your application code isn't expecting it. if you give them values your code won't break anymore.

Comment: cant you change datatype to varchar or something

Answer (score 0):

Youre lucky I still have a 2000 instance.
To prevent this from happening you need to set your date field like such.
Default it to `('1900-01-01 00:00:00')` then dont allow nulls.  Once you save it will populate all null data on that field.

[image]

Just remember on your app output that this date is equal to null (in reality)